# Why is this specific method containing static, not printing to the console?

Tags: java

In the code below, the method `onOrOff()` must be printed to the console, stating engine is off. However, this specific method will not print.

I have tried `System.out.println("engine is off");`, but an error occurs stating “*missing return statement*”.

What is the main reason why the method `onOrOff()` is not shown in the output?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vehicle truck = new Vehicle(200, 8, "red", 5);

    System.out.println(truck.size);
    System.out.println(truck.wheels);
    System.out.println(truck.color);
    System.out.println(truck.numbofGears);
    onOrOff();
}

Vehicle(int size, int wheels, String color, int numbofGears) {
    this.size=size;
    this.color=color;
    this.wheels=14;
    this.numbofGears=numbofGears;
}

static String onOrOff() {
    return Engine is off;
}
```

Comment: `Engine is off` is not a string. Also you need to print the return value of the method

Comment: use double quotes, like this:       return "Engine is off";

Comment: When you got *missing return statement*, what did that code look like? Because the code written currently doesn't compile

Comment: @NathanHughes: just forgot the double quotes, thanks! In the main method, System.out.println(onOrOff()); was added, and now this method is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnholySheep  already answered the question; but I will try to add a bit more details:

> `Engine is off` is not a string. Also you need to print the return value of the method.

Erratum: Nathan Hughes did too

> use double quotes, like this: `return "Engine is off";`

---

If you want a **String**, you have to surround the word(s) with double quotation marks, for example: `"Hello World"`, or `Foo`.

So, in your example, you will have to use `return "Engine is off"` instead; `return Engine is off` by itself won't work.

---

Unrelated question, but why in the *Vehicule* constructor, you have a *wheels* parameter, but you give the associated attribute another value (`14`) regardless of the parameter?

Is that only temporary?

Comment: Yes, that attribute (14) is only temporary. In Java, for printing any line of statement, it must be in the main method, public static void main(String[] args)? Because when executing the system.out.println(onOrOff()) in the method String onOrOff(), it did not work.

Comment: (1/2) No, not forcibly.


Theoretically, a recursive call like this will end up in an endless recursive spiral of calls to `onOrOff()` which will print itself to get to the return, which will print itself to get to the result, *ad infinitum*.

Comment: (2/2) You could use a local String variable that would contain the return value before you actually return it, so that you will be able print that variable and return it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your onOrOff() method returns a String and you're calling this method from main, yet you're not doing anything with the returned String. Try the following:

```
System.out.println(onOrOff());
```